# How Do I Get Nano to Freeze the Top Line While Scrolling?

Tags: nano

I'm using **nano** to view large data sets (I pipe them into **nano** by running `...some process that produces hundreds of rows of stdout | nano -`).

I like this interface, but wish to freeze the top-most line of text (which I would like to serve as a header of sorts) as I scroll down through the hundreds of lines of output.

I've looked everywhere, but mostly get hits from folks asking the same question about the `Excel` spreadsheet app...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open two instances of *nano* and leave one set to the header. Overlap with the header in background. To be a bit more elegant, open the header instance [read-only](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nano.html) with the `--view` command-line option.

Another option is to use the `--smarthome` option to jump back to the header, but I knopw of no way to keep disparate sections in view in one instance.

Comment: Interesting idea...alternatively (wrt said `--smarthome` mention), my version of _nano_  (2.2.6) allows me to jump back to said header with a simple ``Alt-\`` keypress.

Comment: Yes, but that was mentioned second because it doesn't *keep* the header open.